Fast processing of large text files in NodeJS
I have to process large text files efficiently in NodeJS and can't seem to improve further than the code below.
The input file is a ~50 Gb files of text, the processing logic is to compute some type of sums and produce an output file of aggregated data.
At first, i hit the Heap Space limit trying to read the whole file at once, so I partionned the reading part into chunks of 1,000,000 lines but that's as fast as I could go, namely 1 hour and 20 mins for 300,000,000 lines. I tried to a promise based approach where the aggregation of the chunks happen in parallel with the next chunk reading, also thought about workers but that's not ideal for passing large data over to the threads.
I would like help in reviewing and improving this code, I am not sure the aggregation does run in parallel of the next read phase or does it?
I am using the line-reader convenience library.
async function parseFileFast(fileName_) {
    var end, start = Date.now();
   ///... basic checks omitted

    var chunkSize = 3000000;
    var chunkIndex = 0; 
    var chunkCounter = 0;
    var lineCounter = 0;
    var chunkData = []; 
    console.log("processing .. " + fileName_);

    var result = [];
    // return new Promise((ok, ko) => {
    lineReader.eachLine(fileName_, async function(line) {
        chunkData.push(line);
        chunkCounter++;
        lineCounter++;

        if (chunkCounter >= chunkSize) {
            console.log("reaching boundary .. " + chunkIndex);
            console.log("processed lines so far .. " + lineCounter); 
            aggregate(chunkData, chunkIndex).then((data) => {
                result.push(...data.frames); 
            }); 
            chunkData = [];
            chunkCounter = 0;
            chunkIndex++;
        }
    }, async function(err) {
        if (err) throw err; 
        var status = writeOutput2(result, fileName_.replace(".csv", "3.csv"));
        end = Date.now();
        console.log("finished processing everything in sec: " + ((end - start) / 1000));
        return status;
    }); 
}

function aggregate(dataSet, index){ 
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        var frames = new Map(); 
        dataSet.forEach((line) => {
            frames = processFrames(line, frames);
        }); 
        var result = { frames: frames, index: index};
        resolve(result);
    })
}


probably the streaming API is worth looking into.

My guess is aggregate is clogging the main thread and the event queue is waiting until this processing is finished on the CPU in order to notify on the next read chunk, try reducing the chunk size and putting aggregate behind a limited pool of worker threads and do the measurement after.
One more thing try reducing the file size you're reading in favor of doing the measurement first with the worker approach

Want to clear some stuff, putting a function inside a promise like aggregate in your case doesn't make it run in parallel, and in order to utilize a parallel execution you need to distribute the load to all of your CPU cores

that's my worry, i assumed promisifying the function will have it run in parallel while the main function is fetching the next chunk

I tried workers but they don't get the data I think it's too big to transfer
